# Sort elements of rows in a matrix with another matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a matrix D of distances between 3 places and 4 persons
example D(2,3) = 10 means person 3 is far away from place 2 of 10 units.

```
D=[23 54 67 32
   32 5  10  2
   3  11  13 5]
```

another matrix A with the same number of rows (3 places) and where A(i,:) correspond to the persons that picked place i

example for place 1, persons 1 and 3 picked it
no one picked place 2
and persons 2 and 4 picked place 3
    A=[1  3  0
       0  0  0
       2  4  0]

I want to reorder each row of A by the persons who are closest to the place it represents.
In this example, for place 1, person 1 is closer to it than person 3 based on D so nothing to do.
nothing to do for place 2
and there is a change for place 3 since  person 4 is closer than 2 to place 3 D(3,2)>D(3,4)

The result should be

```
A=[1  3  
   0  0  
   4  2 ]
```

each row(place) in A can have 0 or many non zeros elements in it (persons that picked it)

Basically, I want to reorder elements in each row of A based on the rows of D (the closest to the location comes first), something like this but here A and D are not of the same size (number of columns).

```
    [SortedD,Ind] = sort(D,2)


    for r = 1:size(A,1)
        A(r,:) = A(r,Ind(r,:));
    end
```

Comment: What language is this? Is it Matlab? You should add the language as a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another Matlab function [`sortrows(C,colummn_index)`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) that can do the trick. It can sort rows based on the elements in a particular column. So if you transpose your matrix `A` (`C = A'`) and extend the result by adding to the end the proper column, according to which you want to sort a required row, then you will get what you want.

To be more specific, you can do something like this:

```
clear all

D=[23 54 67 32;
   32 5  10  2;
   3  11  13 5];

A=[1  0;  
   3  0;  
   4  2 ];

% Sort elements in each row of the matrix A,
% because indices of elements in each row of the matrix D are always
% ascending.
A_sorted = sort(A,2);
% shifting all zeros in each row to the end
for i = 1:length(A_sorted(:,1))
    num_zeros = sum(A_sorted(i,:)==0);
    if num_zeros < length(A_sorted(i,:))
        z = zeros(1,num_zeros);
        A_sorted(i,:) = [A_sorted(i,num_zeros+1:length(A_sorted(i,:))) z];
    end;
end;

% Prelocate in memory an associated array of the corresponding elements in
% D. The matrix Dr is just a reduced derivation from the matrix D.
Dr = zeros(length(A_sorted(:,1)),length(A_sorted(1,:)));

% Create a matrix Dr of elements in D corresponding to the matrix A_sorted.
for i = 1:length(A_sorted(:,1))  % i = 1:3
    for j = 1:length(A_sorted(1,:))  % j = 1:2
        if A_sorted(i,j) == 0
            Dr(i,j) = 0;
        else
            Dr(i,j) = D(i,A_sorted(i,j));
        end;
    end;
end;

% We don't need the matrix A_sorted anymore
clear A_sorted

% In order to use the function SORTROWS, we need to transpose matrices
A = A';
Dr = Dr';

% The actual sorting procedure starts here.
for i = 1:length(A(1,:))  % i = 1:3
    C = zeros(length(A(:,1)),2);  % buffer matrix
    C(:,1) = A(:,i);
    C(:,2) = Dr(:,i);
    C = sortrows(C,2);
    A(:,i) = C(:,1);
    % shifting all zeros in each column to the end
    num_zeros = sum(A(:,i)==0);
    if num_zeros < length(A(:,i))
        z = zeros(1,num_zeros);
        A(:,i) = [A(num_zeros+1:length(A(:,i)),i) z]';
    end;
end;

% Transpose the matrix A back
A = A';

clear C Dr z
```

Comment: But here the sorting is based on matrix D not a single column

Comment: I don't quite understand exactly how do you want to sort you matrix. Could you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: The next question is: why A is not a matrix 3x4? For example, if all persons choose the first place, then there should be 4 elements in the first row of the matrix A, something like this: A = [1 3 2 4; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0]. Right? So it's not clear how matrix A is formed, the meaning of it is clear though but it doesn't correspond to the form of matrix A.

Comment: If let's say 5 persons choose location 1, 2 persons choose location 2 and no none choose location, then A will have 5 columns (based on the longest assignment). For location 2 and 3, the columns at end will be filled wth 0. If the most chosen location is by 3 persons then the matrix A will be size 3x3 and so on. Its size is variable depending on the assignment.

Comment: but in your case, the longest assignment is by 2 persons: 2 persons chose the place 1, and 2 persons chose the place 3. So, the number of columns should be 2 then, but instead your matrix A have the third column filled with zeros. Why?

Comment: It was a mistake in my example, the function gives me as explained in the previous comment so it will be 2 for this example as you stated

Comment: Did it work for you? If it did, please, don't forget to mark the answer as the best one. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask, I will explain them to you.

Comment: Sorry, I could not log for a few days. Thanks for your answer.